# Opening 2nd window before closing 1st window in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pygtk

In my pygtk app, I want to close current window after opening next window.

this is the code which i have written

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example base.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import subprocess

class Base:
    def next(self,widget):
        subprocess.call('fabfile.py', shell=True)
        self.window.destroy()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(200,200)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Next")
        self.button.show()
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.next)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

when I click on next button it opens next window but it does not close my current window in background and current window go to hang in background after opening next window.

```
def next(self,widget):
   subprocess.call("fabfile.py", shell=True)
   self.win.destroy()
```

when i run this code in

`window machine` it is not closing existing window and

`Linux machine` it is giving this error.

`/bin/sh: fabfile.py: command not found`

Anyone let me know how to resolve this. Thanks...

Comment: on linux: `subprocess.call('fabfile.py', shell=True)` should be `subprocess.call('.\fabfile.py', shell=True)`.  It has to do with the current working directory not being included when searching for a script.

Comment: I have tried with ur suggestion but it is giving same error. any other idea you have for resolving.

Comment: @cstrutton: `'\f'` is a single character (ASCII Formfeed). You need to escape backslash e.g., using a raw string literal `r'\f'` (two characters). You might mean `'./local_command'` instead anyway (if you are not on Windows). And usually `fabfile.py` is not called directly but using `fab` command. `subprocess.Popen('fab')` starts `fab` command without waiting for it to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will work but I am not sure,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["fabfile.py"], bufsize=2048, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
self.win.destroy()
```

`subprocess.Popen` will open your 2nd window and close after current window.

Comment: thanks it's not hanging but some time it's closing without wait for opening. there is any attribute `wait` for opening.

Comment: logically you can do it. create any global variable when new window open, change the value of global variable like 1 and read in file before closing window.